# Central authentication service(CAS). Warning about POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas

For authorization I use CAS. My settings look like this:
web.xml:

```
...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
       <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
...
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/denied.jsp">
    <security:custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="casAuthenticationFilter" after="CAS_FILTER"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/denied.jsp"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.jsp"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" />
    <property name="proxyReceptorUrl" value="/secure/receptor" />
</bean>

<bean id="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"/>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="jdbcUserService"/>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas" />
            <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" />
            <property name="proxyCallbackUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/mywebsite/secure/receptor" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only"/>
</bean>

<bean id="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" class="org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl" />

<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="https://localhost:8443/mywebsite/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
</bean>

 <!-- This filter handles a Single Logout Request from the CAS Server -->
<bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter"/>
<!-- This filter redirects to the CAS Server to signal Single Logout should be performed -->
<bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_cas_security_logout"/>
    <constructor-arg value="https://localhost:8443/cas/logout"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcUserService"
    ...
</bean>
```

Everything is working well. But I have a page which every second sends a POST request to a different page and on every request I get the following message in console:

> WARN  [org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-2)
>   safeGetParameter called on a POST HttpServletRequest for
>   LogoutRequest.  Cannot complete check safely.  Reverting to standard
>   behavior for this Parameter.

In the source code, I found a method that prints a warning:

```
public static String safeGetParameter(final HttpServletRequest request, final String parameter) {
    if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) && "logoutRequest".equals(parameter)) {
        LOG.warn("safeGetParameter called on a POST HttpServletRequest for LogoutRequest.  Cannot complete check safely.  Reverting to standard behavior for this Parameter");
        return request.getParameter(parameter);
    }
    return request.getQueryString() == null || request.getQueryString().indexOf(parameter) == -1 ? null : request
            .getParameter(parameter);
}
```

It turns out that if the request method is a POST, output a warning.
How do I fix this?

Comment: This is an example of the terrible logging in Spring. When trolling the log files it would be nice if these error messages actually wrote out what the parameter was (i.e. "logoutRequest") that caused this warning. Instead you have to download the source code and then find the true value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is found. It was necessary to update the cas-client-core.

Comment: What version did you upgrade to?